# Does the F3 button work on PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I press my F3 button (which is also my lighting button) in minecraft, the info screen does not pop up. It just shows my lighting bar. Does the F3 button work in 1.8.9 PC? With Optifine or Forge? Not in Mineplex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. (I only tested on Vanilla)

If it doesn't, try <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, or a virtual keyboard.

Comment: I'm using Vanilla Minecraft. Is Minecraft still in Vanilla if there are resource packs installed?

Comment: @JoyPlaysRoblox Yes. Try pressing FN+F3 too, as some vendors swap them.

Comment: Hit the green arrow on answer if this helped you!